# How to read cookie in Android 1.6?

Tags: android, cookies

I face prob in add & read cookie from default browser.
I want to save some value in user default browser and next time i want dat value
I m setting cookie

```
BasicClientCookie c = new BasicClientCookie("AppN", "CookN");
    c.setValue("Value");
    c.setDomain("New Domain");
    c.setPath("/newPath");
    c.setComment("new Comment");
    c.setExpiryDate(new Date("11/02/2012"));
    String s = c.toString();
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
    cookieManager.setCookie("http://www.myssec.com",s);
```

is it ok
if yes den can u write code to read cookie
else how to add cookie
plz i m new in android

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to actually accomplish.  Using a cookie may not be the right method to do that.

Comment: @user354505: I am afraid of the accpeted answer and indeed it is a question.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Thnx, i want to get cookie from server and den dat cookie i want save on user side(in default browser), I know how to get from server But I get prob in store it to user default browser. or some wer in webview

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are trying to accomplish.  Using a cookie may well not be the appropriate solution.  Please explain what actual functionality you need to accomplish.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: In simple word i want to store some key and value on user side; which may myapp can access next time

Comment: Then why not store it in your app's private storage?

Answer (score 0):

> I face prob in add & read cookie from default browser.

That is not possible, sorry.

> I want to save some value in user default browser and next time i want dat value I m setting cookie

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Thanx for reply, den how can i store value client side

Comment: after the line cookieManager.setCookie("http://www.myssec.com",s); I put line --System.out.println("@@@@ cookieManager.getcookie :: "+cookieManager.getCookie("http://www.myssec.com")); but it gives null

Comment: in place of line CookieManager.getInstance(); cookieManager.setCookie("http://www.myssec.com",s);  if i put cs = new BasicCookieStore();
cs.addCookie(c);
DefaultHttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
http_client.setCookieStore(cs);
List<Cookie> listC = http_client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
  if(listC.isEmpty(){
 Log.d("httpPost", "None");
}else{
for (int i = 0; i < listC.size(); i++)
{Log.d("httpPost", "- " + listC.get(i).toString());System.out.println("@Cookie.."+listC.get(i).toString());
}} it gives me value but it can't store default browser

Comment: @user354505: The code you have does NOT "add & read cookie from default browser". So, no, it does not work on 2.2. You cannot "add & read cookie from default browser" due to privacy reasons.

Comment: ok, so i cannot add&read cookie from default browser, Plz can u suggest any alternative for that.